# Nuxtjs - <nuxt-link :to> in SSR mode returns href="/"

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a named route in Nuxt that accepts 6 parameters:

[image: Search route with 6 parameters]

The `<nuxt-link>` looks like this:

```html
<nuxt-link :to="localePath({ name: 'search-item-location-inventory-city-page-radius', 
  params: { 
    item: slugify(item), 
    location: slugify(city.name),
    inventory: inventoryId, 
    city: city.id, 
    page: 1, 
    radius: addressMaxRadius()
  }
})">
  {{ item }}
</nuxt-link>
```

Where each attribute looks like this:

- `item` - 'item-name'
- `location` - 'amsterdam'
- `inventory` - 5
- `city` - 25
- `page` - 1
- `radius` - 60

In the HTML code with SSR enabled, the "href" attribute should look like this:

`href="/search/item-name/amsterdam/5/25/1/60"`

but it looks like this:

`href="/"`

My `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: true,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'server',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/app.scss'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/axios.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/bootstrap.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/chart.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/lodash.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/maps.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/moment.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/mixins.js' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    'nuxt-vue-select'
  ],

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true,
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data',
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/potato/authentication/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/potato/users/current',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'data'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/potato/authentication/logout',
            method: 'post'
          }
        },
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      home: false
    }
  },

  axios: {
    baseUrl: process.env.API_BASE_URL
  },

  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    icons: false,
  },

  fontawesome: {
    icons: {
      solid: true,
      regular: true,
      brands: true
    }
  },

  i18n: {
    detectBrowserLanguage: false,
    strategy: 'prefix',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'pl',
        name: 'Polski',
        file: 'pl.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-us.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: false,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'pl'
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {}
}
```

What could be the cause of SSR not generating proper `href` attribute?

Comment: So, does it work in SSG, SSR or SPA at all? Also, did you tried without the `localePath` part? Is it any better? What is `slugify` doing? Does it achieves what you want? Can you double check with your Vue devtools?

Comment: It works in SPA. I'll try removing `localePath`

Comment: Okay, so `ssr: false` + `target: 'static'` is working (SPA)? Keep us updated for the locale one yes please.

Comment: `slugify` converts for instance "New York" to "new-york"

Comment: So the issue is with the addressMaxRadius() - I'm working on fixing that now.